# Linear Regression Results explained

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, normalization

I have a set of stocks fundamentals, and I want to draw some features out of it.
One of the feature I'm trying to create is net income of a certain year divided by the sales for that year.
Now, I'm looking at that feature for the same company over the past 3 years, for example. So I have 3 points in time.
I want to represent those three points as a single number/feature, that would be comparable to other companies so I thought a linear regression slope would do the job.
Now, for it to be comparable I normalized the numbers by dividing them by the first number. So each series starts at 1. The Y's are simply 1,2,3..

Then, I do a simple Linear Regression, but some results seems weird, for example:

linregress([1.0,0.999056,1.007563] , [1,2,3])

gives me the following results:

```
slope=173.91650416497581,
intercept=-172.3002219453318,
rvalue=0.81096563459856597,
pvalue=0.3978846211541317,
stderr=125.47691503758661)
```

The numbers say that in the second year the net income out of the sales dropped by 0.000944%, and in the third there's a change of 0.7%, so how come the slope is so large?

Do you have any other suggestion in order to compose such a feature in a comparable manner?

Comment: Much confusion here. On whether income/sales is a suitable measure: that's for you to decide. But if any regression applies it's that predicting your measure from time, not time from your measure, which you applied here. Change from year 1 to year 2 is a fractional decrease of 0.000944 and a percent decrease that divided by 100. Change from year 2 to year 3 comes from the ratio 1.007563/0.999056 = 
1.008515 which is 0.008515 as a fractional change and that divided by 100 as a percent.  So short answer: Wrong regression. Slightly longer answer: and  do take care over arithmetic.

Comment: Even if you reverse the regression as in @NickCox's suggestion, a slope based on just 3 data points is likely to be very unstable.  And, in a context like this, ratios will tend toward rather extreme and misleading values.  You won't need to pay attention to the first decimal place, let alone the 14th.  Why not create an indicator that relies on 3-year net income?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I accidentally switched the X's and Y's. @rolando2, using net income by itself is a problem since bigger companies make more money, I want to have some equal ground. Whay do you say that ratios tend to provide extreme results?